# Unable to allocate memory for pool, How to fix it

Tags: php, debian, nginx

I am hosting a number of websites on my Debian server running on NginX, all of my website's log files shows me an error like this

> 2011/11/23 10:01:03 [error] 5320#0: *349 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP
>   Warning:  Unknown: Unable to allocate memory for pool. in Unknown on
>   line 0" while reading response header from upstream

I am using APC 3.1.6 with the latest version on PHP and Nginx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723316/warning-require-once-function-require-once-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-p

Comment: I have tried it, it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: And how is it configured?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue:

- I reconfigured php-fpm (see my [php-fpm.conf](https://github.com/till/easybib-cookbooks/blob/master/php-fpm/templates/default/php-fpm.conf.erb)) to recycle processes more often and also how to react when processes don't respond anymore or throw errors
- I configured APC (see my [apc.ini](https://github.com/till/easybib-cookbooks/blob/master/php-fpm/files/default/apc.ini)) to use `apc.mmap_file_mask=/dev/zero`

Then the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Change you apc.ini settings like below

```
apc.mmap_file_mask=/dev/zero
apc.shm_size=64M
apc.ttl=0
```

it works

Refer [apc.configuration.php](http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php)