# Centos is using all memory for cache and not giving it up

Tags: centos, nginx, memory, cache, php-fpm

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1024       1020          3          0          0        859
-/+ buffers/cache:        160        863
```

With 863 "free" for programs, everything is getting memory issues. All webpages have

```
Warning: Unknown: Unable to allocate memory for pool. in Unknown on line 0
```

How can I figure out what the hell is eating up 859mb of memory in the cache and free it up?

I'm using nginx with php-fpm and mysql.

Comment: That's probably not the problem. What is your php-fpm configuration for your pool? And, is this an OpenVZ VPS?

Comment: First of all find out who exactly is using most of your memory. Use `top` or `ps`.

Comment: Its a vps provided by my hosting, thats all that I know. What would you like to know about the php-fpm configuration? I have it set to dynamic, 10 max, 5 start, 3 spare min, 8 spare max. (I could go higher, but I dont see the need with the current load). I ran a load test with 500 concurrent connections earlier today after I changed the settings and it worked fine.

Comment: Your php-fpm settings sound fine. First try restarting php-fpm. If you still have this same trouble, it's probably a problem with the hosting provider. This is why I won't touch OpenVZ-based VPSes with a ten foot pole...

Comment: @Michael Hampton I restarted php-fpm, mysql, nginx, and then the server. The server restart removed the error message, but I still have high cache usage. What would be the cause on the hosts end then?

Comment: Also. Why do I get an error message when I try to use

    echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

I get permission denied.

Comment: Linux is supposed to be using all the free memory as disk cache. This is not something you can (or even should) turn off. IF a program actually needs the memory, it will be able to get it - unless you're using an OpenVZ VPS.

Comment: I don't believe this is a linux memory issue.  Take a look instead at PHP configurations, e.g., http://serverfault.com/questions/333996/unable-to-allocate-memory-for-pool-how-to-fix-it

Comment: How do I find out if its an OpenVZ vps?

Comment: Tell me what php configurations I should change then? Then only things I've touched in over 2 weeks is reduced the number of php-fpm processes.

Comment: This sounds like a broken APC configuration. Perhaps the cache is so small and/or the TTL so high that everything in the cache is valid, the cache is full, and more cacheable PHP scripts are being executed. `apc.ttl=0` can help. Also, don't use APC along with another PHP accelerator.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with APC. I was using the full 64mb of the cache. I increased it to 120mb and everything seems to be working smoothly now.

For anyone else having this issue, to increase your cache size, go to php.ini (or php.d directory and find apc.ini if it exists) and add or change

```
apc.shm_size=64M
```

To whatever the value that you want it to be.

Comment: I'd accept this answer so people can view it as part of the wiki in the future.